# iphone-AVAudio Player Crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, avaudioplayer

I have an app that uses an avaudio player for two things. One of them is to play an explosion sound when a uiimageview collision is detected, and the other is to play a lazer sound when a button is pressed. I declared the audioplayer in the .h class, and I call it each time the button is clicked by doing this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"/lazer"
                                     ofType:@"mp3"]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
               initWithContentsOfURL:url
               error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
[audioPlayer play];
```

This works fine, but after many uses of the game, the audio will stop play when i hit the button, and when a collision is detected, the game crashes. Here is my crash log:

2013-09-18 18:09:19.618 BattleShip[506:907] 18:09:19.617 shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.41.2619" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24 (lldb)

Suggestions? Could there be something to do with repeatedly creating an audio player? Alternatives maybe?